# Is the intermediate value theorem saying that if f is continuous, then it is onto?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

How can I prove

if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\overline{f(\mathbb{N})} = \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is onto (surjective)

by the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by the second condition?

Comment: If $\overline{f(\mathbb N)}$ means "*closure* of $f(\mathbb N)$ is $\mathbb R$" then the statement holds, but this makes for quite a convoluted function $f$. (A good topic for another MSE post: find at least one such function!) On the other hand, if $\overline{f(\mathbb N)}$ is something like *range* in which $f(\mathbb N)$ takes values, i.e. the interval $(\inf f(\mathbb N),\sup f(\mathbb N))$, then the statement still holds, and it is altogether a more natural statement - but $\overline{f(\mathbb N)}$ is not the way to write that, as $\overline{X}$ is commonly used to mean *closure* of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there exist $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n_1)<y, f(n_2)>y$. IVT implies the existence of $x\in [n_1,n_2]$ or $[n_2,n_1]$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question.